# Converting XML string into array in ASP classic

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to convert a string that represents an xml to an array in ASP classic.

I'm getting the string from another page and it contains HTML tags as well as XML tags. I'm cutting the string and removing anything but the XML part, and load it as an XML document. My problem is looping through the XML elements, when I try to run `documentElement.SelectNodes` with any of my tags I get the following error:

> Description:Object required: '[object]'

This is a part of my code in order to understand:

The XML string:

```vb
XmlString = XmlString & "<list> "
XmlString = XmlString & "<pax>"
XmlString = XmlString & "<base64>gdfgdf</base64><paxid>668</paxid> </pax> "
XmlString = XmlString & "<pax>"
XmlString = XmlString & "<base64>gfdgdfgdfg</base64> "
XmlString = XmlString & "<paxid>669</paxid> "
XmlString = XmlString & "</pax> "
XmlString = XmlString & "</list>"

response.Write XmlString
```

And my code is

```vb
sURL = "http://someurl.com"

Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xml.Open "GET", sURL, False
xml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"  
xml.Send

resStr = xml.responseText
newstr = Mid(resStr, InStr(resStr, "<list>"), InStr(resStr, "</list>"))
response.Write newstr

Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
xmlDoc.LoadXML(newstr)

'here is where I get the error (in any of those)
response.Write xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*")
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("pax/").ChildNodes
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("paxid")
```

Comment: I would suspect that `newstr` doesn't contain a valid XML string. What is the value of that variable? What is the output of a line `response.Write xmlDoc.ParseError` placed after `xmlDoc.LoadXML(newstr)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mid` takes a string, start position, and length. So when you're building `newstr` you should do this:

```
startAt = InStr(resStr, "<list>")
endAt = InStr(resStr, "</list>") + 7  ' to get to the end of the closing tag
newstr = Mid(resStr, startAt, endAt - startAt + 1)
```

There is a lot of error checking that should be done to verify that the opening and closing tags you're looking for really do exist, but this explains why you're not getting a valid XML document.

EDIT:

I assumed the problem here was the fact that `newstr` does not contain a valid XML string because of the way it is constructed. So that's the problem I solved. While investigating the undocumented downvote, I determined that there are other problems in the subsequent called on the `xmlDoc` object. Once you get a good XML document in there it will be easier to debug.

The first call (`SelectNodes`) fails because you're trying to write out the value of the object but the call returns an array of nodes and nothing that `response.write` can do anything with.

The second call (`SelectSingleNode`) fails due to some kind of problem with the parameter that is probably easily fixed if you know what you're doing.

The third call (`GetElementsByTagName`) works fine once you apply my corrections to the way `newStr` is built.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with the sub string. I changed it like your recommendation and now it working well